# Pentaho - What step to use to flip parts of a table?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have a table with 4 columns (Date, Asset, Buy, Sell) and would like to transform it into a new one containing Date, Asset, Type (of transaction), Unit by conserving all the relevant values. I am struggling to find out how to do this simply using data integration, if possible at all. I have attached a screenshot of my input (top table) along with my desired output (bottom table). Any idea on how I could proceed? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

[initial table vs final table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzksK.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The step you need is the Row Normaliser. Inside the Pentaho installation you have a folder named samples with examples on how to use different steps or some common techniques. There are two examples available on how to use the Row Normaliser step (conveniently named as Row Normalis/zer - xxxx)

Comment: Thank you! I managed to figure it out using Row Normaliser, by pivoting the two columns and filtering out all the new rows with no numerical values.